# SoQL query for unique values with Socrata API

Tags: sql, json, unique, soql, socrata

I am trying to count the total unique number of heating complaints in the Socrata NYC 311 service requests database: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Social-Services/All-Heat-complaints-to-311/m5nm-vca4

Ideally I want to use the data to populate a map with unique complaints, as well as the number of complaints by each unique address. So far I have used the following query which only returns about 2 days of data:

http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/m5nm-vca4.json?$select=created_date,longitude,latitude,COUNT(*)&$group=created_date,longitude,latitude&$where=complaint_type=%27heating%27

Is there anyway to query the database for unique address across all dates and count them by total complaints?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a little more descriptive about what you're trying to get? An example of the output you're trying to get would be perfect.

I think we might be able to get what you're looking for, but we need to get the aggregation right.

Comment: Currently my query returns JSON objects that count the number of times in a day a complaint was made for a unique lat/long. I would like it to return a JSON object that counts the TOTAL times across ALL dates a complaint was made for a unique lat/long. something like: 

{
  "count" : "257",
  "longitude" : "-73.96272830255063",
  "latitude" : "40.79499980236831"
}

Comment: The query that makes most sense to me is `http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/m5nm-vca4.json?$select=longitude,latitude,COUNT(*)&$group=longitude,latitude&$where=complaint_type=%27heating%27` how ever this returns an internal error with no other explanation